# Bookmarklets doesnt work when run from bookmark, but works from console

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklet that will insert some text in a textarea on a webpage (webpage is for internal use so no point in linking).

Here is example of javascript code i tried:

```
(function(){document.getElementById("textareaID").value="Some text";})();
```

*I'd like to point out that i tried different element selectors (byClass, query...) and different attributes (even tabindex) to the same result. Also tried in both Chrome and IE11.*

So, for some weird reason my javascript runs when i run it from console (or as a snippet) but i get an error *"Cannot set property 'value' of null"* when i try to run it from bookmark menu.

I tried creating a bookmarklet by myself

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById("textareaID").value="Some text";})();
```

and tried using online bookmarklet creators to encode special characters

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById(%22textareaID%22).value=%22Some%20text%22;})();
```

but no luck.

Bookmarklets definitely work on a page (tried with alert "Hello") but i seem to have a problem "capturing" elements. 
Also i noticed that ID's of some elements change sometimes (not sure why though), but i always inspect to make sure that ID i try to use exists or i use some fixed value like tabindex. Besides, as i said it works when run from console, so i couldn't have screwed it up somehow... or could have i?

Comment: Is page with the textarea open and loaded when you run this?

Comment: Could you try to run this `javascript:console.log(document.querySelector('*'))` and see if it logs anything in the console?

Comment: Yes, page with textarea is open and active, so i assume its fully loaded.
When i run console.log code from bookmarklet it does log to console (i assume its entire html document).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was execution context.
Because IDs of elements were changing i had to inspect them before running js from console and inspecting changes the execution context from *top* to wherever the element is. That's why it was working from console and not from bookmark...

So, to write into a textbox inside specific frame:

```
let Iframe =  document.getElementById('yourIframe').contentWindow.document
let value = Iframe.getElementById("textboxID").value = "Some Text"
```

After that only thing left is to wrap everything inside a `javascript:(function(){..your code here..})();` to create a bookmarklet.

Comment: Aahhhh it is the `.contentWindow.document` part that I'm missing!!!   You are a saint for posting the answer to your own question.